# Java SequenceInputStream

Tags: java, file, stream, inputstream

I try to send multiple Files from my Server (NanoHttpd) to my Client (Apache DefaultHttpClient).
My approach is to send multiple files via one Response of NanoHttpd.
For this purpose i wanted to use SequenceInputStream.
I am trying to concatenate multiple Files, send them via the Response (InputStream) and write every File again in a seperate File with my Client.
On the Serverside i call this:

```
List<InputStream> data = new ArrayList<InputStream>(o_file_path.size());
for (String file_name : files)
{
    File file = new File(file_name);
    data.add(new FileInputStream(file));
}
InputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(data));
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, "application/octet-stream", is);
```

Now my Question is how to receive and split the Files correctly.
I have tried it this way on my client, but it does not work:

```
int read = 0;
int remaining = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer];

// Read till the end of the Stream
while ( (read != -1) && (counter < files.size()))
{
    // Create a .o file for the current file
    read = 0;
    remaining = is.available();

    // Should open each Stream          
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        read = is.read(bytes);
        remaining = remaining - read;
        os.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }

    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

This way I want to go over all Stream (untill read == 1, or i know there is no file anymore), and read any stream into a file.

I clearly seem to understand something groundbreaking wrong, since is.available() always is 0.
Could anyone please tell me how to read properly from this SequencedInputStream, or how to solve my Problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a delimiter which is the file size and append that. Then read that many bytes, then the, say, 8 byte size of the next file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work this way. SequenceInputStream will merge all input streams in one solid byte stream. There will be no separators or EOFs. I suggest to abandon the idea and look for a different approach.